# _SESSION increment function

Tags: php, function, session

My function:

```
function SessionSet($s, $v = '') {
    if (is_array($s)) {
        foreach ($s as $k => $v) $_SESSION[$k] = $v;
    } else {
        $_SESSION[$s] = $v;
    }
}
```

It's possible make it work like this:

```
SessionSet('user_visits')++;
```

Just a simple increment, but don't have any ideas how...

Comment: the function seems quite useless to me.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel for you maybe yes, for me - no.

Comment: for everyone. instead of calling `SessionSet($s, $v);` you can always call `$_SESSION[$s] = $v;` which is more convenient and flexible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
$_SESSION['user_visits']++;
```

instead?

You cannot increment the return value of a function - there's nowhere for the incremented value to be stored.

Comment: Then how about: SessionSet('user_visits', ++);  ?

Comment: `++` is an operator. it cannot exist by itself like that. You could pass in `'++'` (a string) and do some if() type stuff internally to implement it, but really.... you seem to be making this far too complicated when a simple `$_SESSION['somevar']++` would do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, always trying new stuff in hardest ways... Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You can return a reference from a function, but still PHP doesn't allow mutator operations on function return values.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like internally in your function? Then when you call function it will do the increment internally. Or have I missed your real question?

```
$_SESSION[$s] = $v; //somewhere in your code you init the variable
//and in your function just do
$_SESSION[$s] = $_SESSION[$s]++;

//Assuming variable in seeion is incrementable!
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to directly change the return value of a function.

It will throw a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

But you could simply access `$_SESSION['user_visits']` after the function call.